# Which constructor initializes the variable x3?

Tags: java

I have found similar question but I am not sure that answer is correct. I had that question on my java exam.

Which constructor initializes the variable x3?

```
class X {
    int x1, x2, x3;
}

class Y extends X {
    int y1;
    Y() {
        x1 = 1;
        x2 = 2;
        y1 = 10;
    }
}

class Z extends Y {
    int z1;
    Z() {
        x1 = 3;
        y1 = 20;
        z1 = 100;
    }
}

public class Test3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Z obj = new Z();
        System.out.println(obj.x3 + ", " + obj.y1 + ", " +obj.z1);
    }
}
```

Answers:

- A. Only the default constructor of class X
- B. Only the no-argument constructor of class Y
- C. Only the no-argument constructor of class Z
- D. Only the default constructor of object class

Thank you for help.

Comment: Share your thoughts please.

Comment: A. makes most sense to me.

Comment: When I use NetBeans dubbuder I see that x1 is inherited and has value 0 at the start. But I am not sure where it is initialized? I think that it can be no argument constructor of class Z.

Comment: @JanZaprawa, no it's not! Think other way,  maybe a _default constructor_ anywhere can help you to think better?

Comment: I suspect also answer: Only the default constructor of class X. X default constructor is called first in my opinion. after X follow other constructors.

Comment: Output of program is x1 = 0 so it has to be answer A. Default constructors of class Z and class Y are never used because classes have own consructors.

Comment: @JanZaprawa Ouput of the program is `0, 20, 100` (`x3 == 0`). And I don't see how it proves anything.

Comment: @JanZaprawa, the output of ` x1` will be `3` not `0`. But of course the output of `x3` will be `0`.

Comment: Yes indeed x3 will be 3. but first initialization in my opinion is 0 because I see this in debugger.I am little bit confused. :P

Comment: I understand that first called is default constructor of super-class after that other constructors so initialization have been made by default constructor of class X.

Comment: Add simple prints to the constructors and get the answer.

Comment: This sounds like a homework task. Please do not use stackoverflow to do your homework this way.

Comment: @Sebastian It is an interesting question and OP did try to solve it himself first. This is a perfectly acceptable question for SO.

Comment: @Manu: Okay. It is clearly indicated that this was a question from a Java exam. I had overseen that a first. But I do not see where the OP tried to solve it by himself - the static void main method is proably part of the test. For the question: I'm not sure where assigning default values to members really happens. Constructor of class 'X' seems natural but there are some subleties (for example consider serialization). According to the SCJP 6 Study Guide assignment of default values happens before the constructor runs -> sounds like 'D' was the expected answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A subclass inherits all the fields of its superclass. So when the constructor of the subclass initializes the class properties, the inherited superclass properties must be initialized too. To ensure this, the constructor of the subclass calls the superclass's constructor first, then goes on with its own constructor.

In your case, `Z` extends `Y` and `Y` extends `X`, so when you write `new Z()`, it calls constructor `Z()`, which implicitly calls `Y()` which calls `X()`. Now where is constructor `X()`? In java, when a class has no constructor, the compiler adds a default no-argument constructor to it. So your class `X` has a constructor `X()` already. This constructor will initialize `x1`, `x2` and `x3` to their default values, which is `0`.

So the situation is, in `main`, you're calling `Z()`, `Z()` is calling `Y()` and `Y()` is calling `X()`. Ultimately the constructor `X()` initializes `x3`.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this answer is correct. No value is explicitly assigned to x3. Hence it gets the default value. However this is set before the constructor of X runs. So this might be done by the constructor of java.lang.Object -> I would think answer 'D' is correct even if that is counter intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize what I've written in some comments:

I think that answer 'D' is correct even if it sounds counter intuitive.
In the shown code there is never a value assigned to x3. Hence it has the default value. This default value is set before the constructor of 'X' runs. Hence the default values must be assigned by something special. I would expect the constructor of Object class to do this. It does some stuff internally required by the VM.

To verify that the field has a value before the constructor runs use a test case:

```
class A {
    A() { printMember(); }

    void printMember() {}
}

class B extends A {
    private int x;

    @Override
    void printMember() { System.out.println(x); }
}

public class TestAssignment {
    @org.junit.Test
    public void createInstance() { new B(); }
}
```

Instead of getting an uninitialized value error it prints '0' - if you overwrite the value in the constructor of B it will still print '0'. This proves that the value is assigned before the constructor of A or B runs. Thus answers A., B. and C. of the question must be wrong and only D. remains.

Comment: Conclusion is: If class does not have own constructor and is not subclass of another class (exception: Object class) - all variables are initialized by default constructor of Object class. Is it correct?

Comment: @Jan: A class always has a  (at least one) constructor. Either ones explicitly defined in the source or the default constructor generated by the compiler (same visibility as class, not always public). Your conclusion sounds correct but I would prefer to say: When the constructor of Object class runs all members get the default value assigned. Initialization canbe tricky. For example the order of member initialization in a class can matter (see Java Puzzlers fo example). Or when dealing with threads and having objects published in an unsafe way (see Java Concurrency in Practice).

Answer (score 2):

Here when you are creating the object of Z class, it will first initialize the default constructor of X class as X is the grand parent class of Z, then initialize the no argument constructor of Y class as Y is the parent class of X and then initialize the no argument constructor of Z class.

When it initialize the default constructor of X, it will assign x1=0, x2=0 and x3=0 as they are all instance variables of class X.

When initialize the no argument constructor of Y class, it will assign x1 = 1,
x2=2 and y1=10.

When initialize the no argument constructor of Z class, it will assign  x1=3,
y1 = 20 and z1 = 100.

So here answar will be option A i.e Only the default constructor of class X.